# CASE Expression in SELECT Statement/ Get away from cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get away from the cursor and rewrite the code under the case expression in select statement.

This is the part of the code that I need to convert:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Ingredients.[Count] AS ICount, 
    dbo.Materials.[Count] AS MCount,
    dbo.Materials.Amount AS MAmount
    CASE
        WHEN MCount < (ICount * @productCount) THEN RETURN 0 
    END
FROM
    dbo.Ingredients
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Materials ON dbo.Ingredients.Material = dbo.Materials.Id
WHERE 
    dbo.Ingredients.Product = @product
```

But in this code I get errors

[image]

This is the part of code with the cursor:

```
DECLARE @ingredientCount FLOAT;
DECLARE @materialCount FLOAT;
DECLARE @materialAmount FLOAT;

DECLARE IngredientCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 
        dbo.Ingredients.[Count] AS ingredientCount, 
        dbo.Materials.[Count] AS materialCount, 
        dbo.Materials.Amount AS materiaAmount, 
        dbo.Materials.Id AS materialId
    FROM 
        dbo.Ingredients 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Materials ON dbo.Ingredients.Material = dbo.Materials.Id
    WHERE 
        dbo.Ingredients.Product  = @product

OPEN IngredientCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM IngredientCursor 
      INTO @ingredientCount, @materialCount, @materialAmount

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    IF (@materialCount < (@ingredientCount * @productCount))
    BEGIN
        CLOSE IngredientCursor
        DEALLOCATE IngredientCursor

        RETURN 0;
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM IngredientCursor 
          INTO @ingredientCount, @materialCount, @materialAmount
END

CLOSE IngredientCursor;
DEALLOCATE IngredientCursor;
```

Can I do this ?

Comment: return(0) jumps out of the whole procedure. why do you wanna do that

Comment: First of all, you're missing a comma before the CASE expression in the SELECT clause. Second, you don't use `RETURN` in CASE expressions. Those errors are throwing the parser off as it tries to evaluate the rest of the query.

Comment: @siggemannen if any material is missing to make a product, I need to return 0 (more than 2-3 different materials may be needed to make a product, and each material needs to be checked for quantity)

Comment: What is the result if you never match the `IF()` expression?

Comment: ok, are your procedure some kind of "control check" procedure?

Comment: you can do if exists(select 1 from sometable where somecondition) return(0) instead of the cursor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what all you are doing with this query, as it selects columns that are never used and produces no result at all when the `IF()` conditional is never matched.

But based only on what we can see, you want to move the `IF()` condition to the `WHERE` clause, rather than a `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` clause, and then you can reduce it to an `IF EXISTS()` check:

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Ingredients i
    INNER JOIN dbo.Materials m ON i.Material = m.Id
    WHERE i.Product  = @product
        AND m.[Count] < (i.[Count] *  @productCount)
) 
BEGIN
    RETURN 0
END
```

The above completely replaces the entire second code block from the question, including the cursor. It's a **LOT** less code and will probably run in a small fraction of the time as the original.